# Not found error when accessing Nagios

Tags: linux, centos7, nagios

I have followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-centos-7 in order to install nagios in my centos 7.8 system

installation went through without problem, however i'm having issues when accessing the GUI

Nagios page opens up after i specify the credentials set with htpasswd
however on the right side of the iframe i get:

```
The requested URL /nagios/< was not found on this server.
```

there's no error in the error logs
and in the access logs i can see:

```
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1933 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/side.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6193 "http://10.0.0.101/nagios/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/%3C?php%20echo%20$url;%20?%3E HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://10.0.0.101/nagios/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/images/sblogo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3231 "http://10.0.0.101/nagios/side.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/stylesheets/common.css?%3C?php%20echo%20$this_version;%20?%3E HTTP/1.1" 200 10166 "http://10.0.0.101/nagios/side.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
10.0.1.36 - nagiosadmin [12/Oct/2020:13:15:03 +0300] "GET /nagios/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 822 "http://10.0.0.101/nagios/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.228"
```

As you can see from these logs there's a 404 error for file

```
/nagios/%3C?php%20echo%20$url;%20?%3E
```

the same file shows up in the browser console log
i've run out of ideas, any clues?

Comment: This guide doesn't mention installing `PHP` so i would verify that first.

Comment: @tbielaszewski Php is installed and running as this is my development server and there are a few domains running php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is related to php not installed or Nagios cannot find it ,
please check link as below :
https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=7740&sid=52943b6873de070610f51bd5228d211d&start=10

Comment: Thanks mate, that pointed me in the right direction.